# Mobile site will not scroll

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, scroll

I am having a problem on the mobile version of a site I am working on. I am using wordpress and the desktop version works ok but the mobile site does not allow scrolling by using the touch screen. I have some position fixed elements I tried taking out and I tried disabling various jquery scripts but I am not quite sure what is causing this issue. I searched the threads and tried various fixes but couldn't get it to work. Any help is appreciated!!! Thank you.

[Here is the link to the site](http://hayes-tavern.com/)

Comment: I see I got a -1, but no reason why. I am new here so if you explain what I did wrong I can better serve the community here later as well as clarify any confusion. I am on android for mobile. I exhausted hours looking here and google and cannot fix the site. Please follow the link and scroll on android mobile and you will see the issue, it may be touch screen related because the menu links still scroll you to sections of the site.

Comment: Lose whatever it is that's doing the scroll jacking, meaning the way it tries to bring certain parts of the page into focus when you scroll. Honestly even when implemented well they're gimmicky and annoying. You have a ton of missing files and javascript errors popping up in the console too.

For the record the -1 is in relation to your question. The goal of SO is to solve specific coding issues, ie you give code you tried that doesn't work, we attempt to fix it. A "it's broken here's a link" doesn't qualify. It seems harsh but it keeps the site clean and working as intended.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't think of whatever you need to do, as a 'fix.' Everything that is happening is because it's not written correctly - and need to be written properly.

I'm on the latest Chrome browser, and although is 'sorta' scrolls - sometime, on the desktop - I would consider the entire thing broken across the board. Unusable. (Certainly not even 1% close to being a WordPress theme you could actually sell... - or use yourself - Brent.)

The culprit is probably a combination of 2 things. First thing, you probably don't truly understand CSS positioning. Everything is doing things and reacting to the other elements in ways you are not in control of. Second thing is that you have tons of parallax scripts - and for many reasons - these are a mess on desktop and especially mobile.

Parallax often works by changing element position to absolute and then using that position to offset and make that effect. Parallax - if used at all (I highly recommend against it) - should be added at the very end as an "enhancement."

The html / body of the HTML document - doesn't know how tall it is unless it can clearly understand the heights of it's child elements. The parallax and other stuff you are doing is making this impossible - and so - the whole distance to scroll is mysterious - and that is most likely why its scrolls all messed up.

I bet you are plugging and playing with a theme of some sort ( a quick 'what wordpress theme is this' search reveals a lot ) - and it's possible you have no intention of learning to program... and in that case - I would suggest getting a square-space site or something and trying to decorate like you have.

However - if you plan on learning - Make this site from scratch - and with no JavaScript. - then later - after the site does all the basics - you can think about adding in some animation effects etc.

While trouble shooting  - put bright color boarders around everything and maybe you'll start to see how the elements are working in the natural flow or otherwise.

Good Luck!